# create div contains input and button inside a main div on click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, onclick

i'm trying to create a new div contains a button and an input inside

i tried to use .prepend() but it can only creates the div and i can't creat the button and the input even when i use .appendChild() allways i get error

---

```js
var secondContainer = $(".second-container");


$("#adding-btn").click(function(){
  secondContainer.prepend("<div class ='dwn-section'></div>");
  $("div .dwn-section").appendChild("input");
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>to do list</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Akaya+Telivigala&family=Kufam&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <h1 class="my">My to do list</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="top-section">
      <input id="inputField" class="inpt" type="text" name="" value="">
      <button id="adding-btn" class="btn btn-info" type="button" name="button">+</button>
    </div>
    <div class="second-container">

    </div>
  </div>







  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="index.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hello, did you saw my answer ? Validate and upvote it if you find it usefull :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here, `$("div .dwn-section")` this statement is not valid. As it is a get element by class name it will be an array, so you should specifiy the index like `$('.dwn-section')[0]`

But at the same time if we are using any specific ID field to get the div then we can directly use `$("#dwn-section")`.

```
$("#adding-btn").click(function(){
  secondContainer.prepend("<div class ='dwn-section' ></div>");
  $('<input>').appendTo($('.dwn-section')[0]);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly the jQuery method to append content is `append()` not `appendChild()`.

Also note that when you're trying to create new HTML content using jQuery you need to include the entire HTML string, not just a tag name.

Lastly, I'm assuming that the new `input` you create should contain the value which was typed in to the original, and that the old input should be cleared. To do that set the `value` attribute in the HTML string for the new input, and use `val('')` to clear the original one:

```js
let $secondContainer = $(".second-container");
let $inputField = $('#inputField');

$("#adding-btn").click(function() {
  let $section = $('<div class="dwn-section"></div>');
  $section.append(`<input type="text" value="${$inputField.val()}" readonly />`);
  $secondContainer.prepend($section);
  $inputField.val('');
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Akaya+Telivigala&family=Kufam&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<h1 class="my">My to do list</h1>
<div class="container">
  <div class="top-section">
    <input id="inputField" class="inpt" type="text" name="" value="">
    <button id="adding-btn" class="btn btn-info" type="button" name="button">+</button>
  </div>
  <div class="second-container"></div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use append()

```js
var secondContainer = $(".second-container");


$("#adding-btn").click(function(){
  secondContainer.prepend("<div class ='dwn-section'></div>");
  $("div .dwn-section").append("<input/>");
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>to do list</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Akaya+Telivigala&family=Kufam&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <h1 class="my">My to do list</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="top-section">
      <input id="inputField" class="inpt" type="text" name="" value="">
      <button id="adding-btn" class="btn btn-info" type="button" name="button">+</button>
    </div>
    <div class="second-container">

    </div>
  </div>







  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="index.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>

</html>
```